# how can I loop to get the list named vlist?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I loop to get the list named vlist?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
data = ['SUMLEV','STNAME', 'CTYNAME', 'CENSUS2010POP']
df=df[data]
adf = df[df['SUMLEV']==50]
adf.set_index('STNAME', inplace=True)
states = np.array(adf.index.unique())
vlist =list()
vlist.append(adf.loc[states[0]]['CENSUS2010POP'].sort_values(ascending =False).head(3).sum())
vlist.append(adf.loc[states[1]]['CENSUS2010POP'].sort_values(ascending =False).head(3).sum())
vlist.append(adf.loc[states[2]]['CENSUS2010POP'].sort_values(ascending =False).head(3).sum())
vlist.append(adf.loc[states[3]]['CENSUS2010POP'].sort_values(ascending =False).head(3).sum())
vlist.append(adf.loc[states[4]]['CENSUS2010POP'].sort_values(ascending =False).head(3).sum())
vlist.append(adf.loc[states[5]]['CENSUS2010POP'].sort_values(ascending =False).head(3).sum())
vlist.append(adf.loc[states[6]]['CENSUS2010POP'].sort_values(ascending =False).head(3).sum())
vlist.append(adf.loc[states[7]]['CENSUS2010POP'].sort_values(ascending =False).head(3).sum())
vlist.append(adf.loc[states[7]]['CENSUS2010POP'].sort_values(ascending =False).head(3).sum())
   
print(vlist)
```

Output:

```
[1406269, 478402, 5173150, 807152, 15924150, 1794424, 2673320, 897934, 897934]
```

Comment: Please format your code. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/8565438) might be useful.

Comment: Also recommend [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: just create a dictionary instead - in one line `df[data].loc[df['SUMLEV']==50].groupby('STNAME')['CENSUS2010POP'].nlargest(3).to_dict()` ; then you can rid your self of code repitition and access each item by its state name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. [List Comprehension](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
data = ['SUMLEV','STNAME', 'CTYNAME', 'CENSUS2010POP']
df=df[data]
adf = df[df['SUMLEV']==50]
adf.set_index('STNAME', inplace=True)
states = np.array(adf.index.unique())


vlist=[adf.loc[states[i]]['CENSUS2010POP'].sort_values(ascending =False).head(3).sum() for i in range(0,7)]
```

Comment: I got ----->>>IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: My bad. I've fixed it. How about now?

Comment: the error was because one of the items has only one value, not a list, so I used try function to skip it, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know, how you can create a loop for your append statements. You can change your code to include the loop as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
data = ['SUMLEV','STNAME', 'CTYNAME', 'CENSUS2010POP']
df=df[data]
adf = df[df['SUMLEV']==50]
adf.set_index('STNAME', inplace=True)
states = np.array(adf.index.unique())

vlist =list()

for i in range(8):
  vlist.append(adf.loc[states[i]]['CENSUS2010POP'].sort_values(ascending =False).head(3).sum())
   
print(vlist)
```

If it doesn't help, please specify your question more and also provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-cd086edc4da8> in <module>()
      9 vlist=list()
     10 for i in range(10):
---> 11     print(adf.loc[states[i]]['CENSUS2010POP'].sort_values(ascending =False).head(3).sum())
     12 

AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'sort_values'

Comment: the error was because one of the items has only one value, not a list, so I used try function to skip it, thank you so much :)